# Opencart ::if (($data['maintenance']==0)) { code appears in site home page?

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

Such code appears in site home page:

```
if (($data['maintenance']==0)) {
```

Can't understand why it's happening...Screenshoot has been attached for reference.

[Code show in homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH9B8.png)

Comment: Open your source files and search for this string, then post the code around it so we can figure out why the PHP parser in echoing this code instead of interpreting it.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.